# Flutter FutureBuilder stuck at ConnectionState.waiting

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm new and currently learning Flutter, I have a question about FutureBuilder. My code is stuck at ConnectionState.waiting and I'm not sure why.

My codes are

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class DartPad extends StatefulWidget {
  const DartPad({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DartPad> createState() => _DartPadState();
}

class _DartPadState extends State<DartPad> {
  List three = [];

  Future<dynamic> fetchData() async {
    var sheetID = '1j7sYExCP0etGw_LoxqYTFRrjwHmJv73SHzC26jbtpH4';
    var sheetTab = 'daftar';
    var url = Uri.parse('https://opensheet.elk.sh/$sheetID/$sheetTab');
    http.Response response;
    response = await http.get(url);

    setState(() {
      three = json.decode(response.body);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('Dartpad'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
        future: fetchData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Text('Loading....');
            default:
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              } else {
                return Text("${three[1]["nama"] ?? ''}");
              }
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried to delete

```
case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Text('Loading....');
```

But received an error.

I have also tried to changed `.hasData` on snapshot (suggested from other thread) but the editor did not accept it.

I tried to not use `switch` and direcly used `if` but received `RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1)` error.

I want to run `three[1]["nama"]` (preferably in loop so I can display the rest of the data)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this happened is that you are not return anything in `fetchData`, change `fetchData` to this:

```
Future<dynamic> fetchData() async {
    var sheetID = '1j7sYExCP0etGw_LoxqYTFRrjwHmJv73SHzC26jbtpH4';
    var sheetTab = 'daftar';
    var url = Uri.parse('https://opensheet.elk.sh/$sheetID/$sheetTab');
    http.Response response;
    response = await http.get(url);

    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
```

then define new variable like this:

```
Future fetchFuture;
```

then use it like this inside `initState`:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  fetchFuture = fetchData();
}
```

then change your last return in your builder to this:

```
FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
    future: fetchFuture,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
          return Text('Loading....');
        default:
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          } else {
            List data = snapshot.data ?? [];
            
            return Text("${data[1]["nama"] ?? ''}");
          }
      }
    },
  )
```

Comment: actually `Future` **should** be obtained from `initState` (or two similar methods), read `FutureBuilder` official docs for more info (the second paragraph)

Comment: Yes you are right, by that I mean calling `fetchData()` twice inside `FutureBuilder` and `initState` is wrong. @pskink

Comment: Yeah I mist that part, I forgot to change it to ` future: fetchFuture,`, thanks for that, @pskink

Answer (score 0):

- There is nothing wrong with your code, it is your own mistake

```
Text("${three[1]["nama"] ?? ''}") 
// Does your List really have two values? 
// Is the Key value really 'nama'? Are you sure it's not a name?
```